# How to export mulitple PDFs from R

Tags: r, data-visualization, pdf

I'm fairly new to R and am running into some issues exporting multiple graphs from R into a PDF file. The graphs I've created are:

```
plot(mirt.nom.cohen.pf.fa2,type="info")
plot(mirt.nom.cohen.pf.fa2,type="infotrace")
plot(mirt.nom.cohen.pf.fa2,type="trace")
```

What would be the most efficient way to export  these to a pdf?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Darko

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way - to save an R graph as a pdf file, you need to:

1. Open the pdf file;
2. Place the graph in that file;
3. Close the pdf file.

What this means in your case is that you have to do something like this:

```
pdf("plot1.pdf")
plot(mirt.nom.cohen.pf.fa2,type="info")
dev.off()

pdf("plot2.pdf")
plot(mirt.nom.cohen.pf.fa2,type="infotrace")
dev.off()

pdf("plot3.pdf")
plot(mirt.nom.cohen.pf.fa2,type="trace")
dev.off()
```

The 3 pdf files you created will be stored in R's working directory, which you can find with the command:

```
getwd()
```

Once you know where R saved the pdf files, you have to locate that directory on your computer and then you can manually select and open the files. Each file will be single-page and contain one graph.

As already suggested here, you can also create a single, multi-page pdf file which will contain all 3 graphs (one graph per page):

```
pdf("plot.pdf")
plot(mirt.nom.cohen.pf.fa2,type="info")
plot(mirt.nom.cohen.pf.fa2,type="infotrace")
plot(mirt.nom.cohen.pf.fa2,type="trace")
dev.off()
```

This file will also be stored in R's working directory.

If you look at the help of the pdf function in R, you'll discover that you can use it with various options (e.g., width and height):

```
help(pdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want one to a page, or all on the same page?
to simply get them to a pdf file, you open the pdf device, indicate the file name, and then everything until you close it will go there.

```
pdf("plots.pdf")
your statements
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris!

I'm just not sure what should go into the "your statements" portion. I know that's what's causing a blank pdf file. But I would like them to be displayed one per page

Comment: your 3 plot statements from the original question (for instance). those 3 plots will then be in that pdf.

Comment: Still having some issues. Just not sure exactly what the code would look like.

Comment: Did you try @Isabella Ghement's code? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Thank you @Isabella Ghement and Chris Umphlett for the guidance. Worked very well!